# structures c++ multiple choice

Tags: c++, c, structure

I want to make a program in c with multiple choice questions  using a structure like this:

```
struct exam
{
    char quest[50];
    char ans1[20];
    char ans2[20];
    char ans3[20];
    int correct_answer;
};
struct exam question[3];/*number of multiple choices*/
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

I'm not sure **how** to fill a structure.

Comment: Is this C or C++?

Comment: use a two dimensional array for the answers.

Comment: Fill with what exactly? `struct exam question[3] = {{{0}}};`. There, it's filled.

Answer (score 3):

If all your data is going to be constant,  you can use something like this:

```
struct question {
  const char *prompt;
  const char *answers[3];
  int correct_answer;
};
```

Then you can set up an array of questions, like so:

```
const struct question questions[] = {
 { "Kernighan & who?", { "Ritchie", "Stroustrup", "Torvalds" }, 0 },
 { /* next question ... */
};
```

If I were to do this, I would probably encode the correct answer in the string, i.e. starting the correct answer with an `'*'` or something. Of course code to process (print and compare) answers will need to take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct exam question[3];
```

defining `question` in this way, that means your are defining array of 3 elements. each element in the array is an `exam` structure

And it could be filled like this:

```
strcpy(question[0].quest, "What's the name of The President?");
strcpy(question[0].ans1, "name 1");
strcpy(question[0].ans2, "name 2");
strcpy(question[0].ans3, "name 3");
question[0].correct_answer = 2;

strcpy(question[1].quest, "What's the surname of The President?");
strcpy(question[1].ans1, "surname 1");
strcpy(question[1].ans2, "surname 2");
strcpy(question[1].ans3, "surname 3");
question[1].correct_answer = 3;
```

And you can fill it in this way too:

```
  struct exam question[3] = {
      {"What's the name of The President?", "name 1", "name 2", "name 3",2}
      {"What's the surname of The President?", "surname 1", "surname 2", "surname 3",3}
      {"What's any thing?", "any thing 1", "any thing 2", "any thing 3",3}
  }
```

Comment: I think this is what OP wants, despite the fact that the names are simply wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your question mentions C++. Your way of doing it is OK in C (except for the fact that the answers should be an array).

But this implementation isn’t acceptable in C++ since there’s a better way to do it:

```
struct question {
    std::string prompt;
    std::vector<std::string> answers;
    int correct_answer;
};
```

That is, use the built-in containers and string classes.